# SurfaceView and overlaying View with Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

In my application I was using a custom SurfaceView to retrieve a picture from the camera, and then a custom View for printing it on screen after drawing additional features over it using a canvas. These two classes were created and added to the layout in the activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myView = new MyView(this);
    mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this, myView);

    setContentView(mySurfaceView);
    addContentView(myView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

and then myView was called back from mySurfaceView using the 
surfaceChanged and surfaceCreated methods:

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

    ...

    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                ...

                System.arraycopy(data, 0, myView.cameraData, 0, data.length);
                myView.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }catch(Exception e){
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

Everything was working fine... *until* I decided to put all of the above in a Fragment in order to use two different views in the same app. Following a tutorial, I put the two classes in the Fragment instead of the Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myView = new MyView(this);
    mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this, myView);       
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mySurfaceView = (MySurfaceView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_view, null);

    return mySurfaceView;
}
```

while the XML layout is:
camera_fragment (I'm not concerning about the other fragment, yet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- "Fragment A" -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/camera_frag"
        android:name="com.example.mypackage.CameraFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

camera_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.example.mypackage.MySurfaceView" >

</view>
```

With the fragment version of the code I can see the SurfaceView with ease, but I don't seem able to print on screen the features that should be drawn by the View. No error code is reported, but the program seems to never enter the setPreviewCallback, and then the onPreviewFrame method. I don't know if it is because of how I instantiate the classes, or how I declare the layout, or both.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? If you did, an answer on this question would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. I've put aside the Fragments at the moment and I'm going on with the FrameLayout. If I'd ever find a solution, I'd post it here for sure :)